# Trying to understand how does realloc and malloc function works

Tags: c, malloc, realloc

Sorry if the question is to basic but i don't really understand why if i don't add "+ 1" the program don't print all the letters

> a = realloc(a, sizeof(char)*(i + 1));

and also in here

> *(a + i) = letra;

Does the position of "a" gets bigger every time it pass?
I suppose that is not the case ,but I'm not very sure.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *copiarFrase();

int main()
{
    char *frase;
    frase = copiarFrase();
    printf("Frase: %s", frase);
    free(frase);
    return 0;
}


char *copiarFrase()
{
    FILE *archivo;
    char letra;
    char *a;
    int i = 0;
    archivo = fopen("frases.txt", "r");
    a = malloc(sizeof(char));
    letra = fgetc(archivo);
    while(letra != EOF)
    {
        *(a + i) = letra;
        i++;
        a = realloc(a, sizeof(char)*(i + 1));
        letra = fgetc(archivo);
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: The only real thing you need to know is how terribly, horribly, deadly wrong this code is.  Google "realloc o(n) complexity" to find the right hits.

Comment: this looks like a question about c strings to me rather than `malloc` or `realloc`. If you treat a `char` array as a string, it must be `NUL` terminated. `printf("%s");` will keep on printing characters until it finds a `'\0'` character. So if you have the string "Hello", you actually need 6 characters to represent the string (the 5 letters plus the `NUL` terminator). This is why you see +1 on memory allocations meant for strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In brief, what your code does is reads from a file 1 byte at a time and continually writes what is read to new places in memory.

**These are the steps:**

allocates 1 byte (8 bits) of memory for a char to store the contents of the file:

```
a = malloc(sizeof(char));
```

**NOTE:** Since this is not enough memory for the entire file, your program continually reallocates, 1 byte at a time in the loop (more commentary on this below).

opens a file stream:

```
archivo = fopen("frases.txt", "r");
```

Reads the first letter from the stream archivo (frases.txt):

```
letra = fgetc(archivo);
```

Starts loop to read until end of file (EOF):

```
while(letra != EOF)
{   
    *(a + i) = letra;
```

This copies the letter read from `fgetc()` to your pointer `a` -- this -> `*(a + i)` is pointer arithmetic.  It essentially means reference the place in memory `i` bytes from memory address `a`.  just `*a` without `( + i)` would write the letter to the beginning of your memory (char pointer).

**Your main question:**

Why `(i + 1)` in `a = realloc(a, sizeof(char)*(i + 1));`?

`realloc()` creates new memory of the requested size and copies the input buffer to the new space, which is probably why [@hans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) critized the code (along with the fact that you read an entire file one char at a time).  A slight improvement would be to read 1024 chars at a time, and then realloc.  To learn more about how to read chars from a file, research stack overflow or google.

Don't forget, `i` keeps incrementing by 1 in this code: `i++`.

**For example,** If you have already read `"hola mundo"` from your file to your buffer `a`, then `i` will have value of `10`.  `realloc()` creates an entire new place in memory.  So, if you allocated 10 bytes, that would be just enough for `"hola mundo"` and the terminating `NULL` byte: `'\0'`, but not enough for the next char `'!'` and the `'\0'` byte.  Thus you need to allocate memory for `i` (which is current length + 1 for the NULL byte) `+ 1` more for the next char.